# What's wrong in the concept/method I applied for the below electromagnetism problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I was told by mathstack community to post it here.

> The setup was this (figure added): [image] a semi infinite wire straight current $I$ being given to a plane sheet (current flows radially there).

- Find magnetic field at a general point.

> By some symmetry reasons one computes it to be $\vec B = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r} \ \hat{k}$ at a point $(r,h,0)$ by Ampere’s Law, the plane being $y=0$ and semi infinite line being the y axis, current direction in that in $-y$ direction.

> Now by integration approach (figure added): [image] I first find the magnetic field due to a current $dI = \frac{I}{2\pi} d\theta$  between $\theta$ and $\theta +d\theta$ angle in the plane at that point,  it comes out to be

- $\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi(h^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta)} \left(1+ \frac{r\cos\theta}{\sqrt{h^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta}}\right)$ ($h\sin\theta \ \hat{i} - r\sin\theta \ \hat{j} + h\cos\theta \ \hat{k})$
- Now integrating in limits $0$ to $2\pi$ the $\hat{i}$ and $\hat{j}$ components goes to zero and we are left with.
- $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi(h^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta)} \left(1+ \frac{r\cos\theta}{\sqrt{h^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta}}\right) (2 h\cos\theta \ \hat{k})$

> This with the straight wire current magnetic field which is standard integral (means easily evaluated) should result in what we get from Ampere’s law as net magnetic field at that point. On comparing we arrived at a result which I mentioned here in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4549382/).

- Now my question is what is wrong in my method: is it Ampere’s law wrongly applied or some error with integration, or am I missing some concept?

Comment: is the plate finite or infinite? This problem looks like a 'half' plane capacitor. I guess that if we can ignore the current in the plate (used as a reservoir of electric charges with uniform distribution) we can ignore the current in it and just evaluating the magnetic field produced by the wire.

Comment: How did you obtain the result for the magnetic field due to the current within an angle $d\theta$?  Are you using the result for the Biot-Savart Law for a semi-infinite wire, perhaps?  Or something different?  Filling in more details might help folks figure out your error.

Comment: You cannot take the current in $d\theta$ as a straight semi-infinite wire, because its width changes with distance from the center. Instead, first decompose the plane in terms of narrow circles, calculate the magnetic field of the a circle with radius $r$ and thickness $dr$ and then integrate over $\theta$.

Comment: Yeah exactly @MichaelSeifert using biot savart law to deduce that magnetic field portion from semi infinite along some point (0,r,h) and then the rest integration for the radial currents (by considering small dtheta current ) which i showed above how i integrated it , can you now tell what makes the final result not correct ? , I will edit it soon for more details of the above which i said

Comment: Oh may you guide a bit in detail of the calculation process you wanted me to apply as an answer for this question ? @Hossein i think i might be easily be able to get what you meant by that :) i will open a bounty again if needed for the great answer

Comment: The result you have for the "small $d \theta$ current" is what I don't understand and what I think is incorrect.  To be sure, you need to explain how you got the result $$\frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi(h^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta)} \left(1+ \frac{r\cos\theta}{\sqrt{h^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta}}\right)(h\sin\theta \ \hat{i} - r\sin\theta \ \hat{j} + h\cos\theta \ \hat{k})$$just below your last drawing.